# Shape of the hidden state of LSTM in Keras

Tags: neural-networks, lstm, keras

I have a question on Keras.

```
from keras.layers import Input, LSTM

inputs1 = Input(shape=(3, 1))
lstm1 = LSTM(1)(inputs1)

print lstm1

>> Tensor("lstm_1/TensorArrayReadV3:0", shape=(?, 1), dtype=float32)
```

In the above code, why is the shape of lstm1 (?, 1) instead of (1)? Doesn't LSTM(1) indicate that the shape of the last LSTM unit should be (1)? Where ? does come from?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You didn't specify the batch size. So Keras with assume that you have a dynamic input size that's why it is marked as '?'

```
inputs1 = Input(shape=(3, 1)) # batch shape = none
lstm1 = LSTM(1)(inputs1) 
print(lstm1.shape)


>> TensorShape([Dimension(None), Dimension(1)]))
```

You can notice that once the batch size is not specified, you get 'None'. 
Let's try to specify a batch size:

```
inputs1 = Input(shape=(3, 1), batch_shape=(2, 1, 1))
lstm1 = LSTM(1)(inputs1)
print(lstm1.shape)
print(lstm1)
>> TensorShape([Dimension(2), Dimension(1)])
>> <tf.Tensor 'lstm_6/TensorArrayReadV3:0' shape=(2, 1) dtype=float32>
```

You can notice that dimension has changed to (2,1) where 2 is the batch size.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Let me ask one more question. If I change LSTM(1) to LSTM(1, return_sequences=True), then the output shape of lstm1 is (?, ?, 1). Shouldn't it be (?, 3, 1), since the sequence length is known (i.e., 3)?

Comment: There is a confusion: 
In fact, printing `lstm1.shape` outputs the shape of the lstm layer before applying it to input, means the lstm layer shape would be a 3D tensor (None, None, 1). (it is not already compiled)
If you want  the output of your model: 
`inputs1 = Input(shape=(3, 1))
lstm1 = LSTM(1, return_sequences=True)(inputs1)
model = Model(inputs=inputs1, outputs=lstm1)
print (model.summary())`

And result will be:
`Layer (type)               |Output Shape 
input_6 (InputLayer)  | (None, 3, 1)          
lstm_6 (LSTM)           | (None, 3, 1)`      
An this is what you expect.

Answer (score 1):

You didn't specify the batch size. TensorFlow (and Keras by extension) allows one or more axes to have their size determined at runtime. This unspecified axis is usually the batch size, but in the case of a sequential model, it can be useful to make that axis the sequence length.